# ML function that adds up a custom data type

Tags: sml, smlnj, ml

So I am given this:

```
datatype intnest = INT of int
                    | LIST of intnest list;
```

I am told to write a function to addup all the integers inside the intnest. One problem being I really don't understand what an intnest could be. Could you give me and exmaple of a valid intnest?

I need something to check my method I wrote against and nothing i try will be accepted.

I have tried things such as:

```
val in1 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3]];
val in2 = [1,2,3,[1]];
```

etc... so if you could give me an example it'd be mighty helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to build up values using constructors starting from base cases. For example, we have the constructor `INT of int` so:

- `INT 1` is of type `intnest`
- `INT 2` is of type `intnest`
- `INT 3` is of type `intnest`

Put three values into a list, you have `[INT 1, INT 2, INT 3]` of type `intnest list`. Now look at the second constructor `LIST of intnest list`, you can easily see that

`LIST [INT 1, INT 2, INT 3]` is an `intnest`.

Repeating the procedure, you also have:

- `[INT 1, INT 2, INT 3, LIST [INT 1, INT 2, INT 3]]` is an `intnest list`
- `LIST [INT 1, INT 2, INT 3, LIST [INT 1, INT 2, INT 3]]` is an `intnest`

Comment: Thank you that was a lot of help, just couldn't get my head around that one.